How to use radio buttons in R Shiny to plot x-axis variable with ggplot2?
I am having trouble with a part of this R Shiny App. I am trying to use radio button input to change the x-axis variable of the point plot that gets displayed. With the code I currently have, the geom_point() plot does not display the data properly. Instead, it just displays a single vertical line of dots.
The data I am using is the train.csv file from the House Prices dataset found on the Kaggle website linked here Link to Kaggle for train.csv file. I am focusing on only sale price (SalePrice), first floor square feet (X1stFlrSF), and second floor square feet (X2ndFlrSF).
Here is some sample code:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#choose the "train.csv" file here
houseData<-read.csv(file.choose())

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  radioButtons("dist", "Square Foot Floor Level:",
               c("First Floor" = "X1stFlrSF",
                 "Second Floor" = "X2ndFlrSF"
               )),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(houseData, aes(x=input$dist,y=SalePrice))+
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Example photos of the plots:
Current output plot
Desired output plot
I have tried using different types of plots such as geom_histogram(), geom_line(), etc. but there is either another error or another vertical line plotted. Even if it is just syntax errors, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to SO.  Your problem is due to the fact that Shiny input widgets (generally) return strings, whereas ggplot functions expect symbols (that identify columns in a data frame) as their argument. This is a feature of the tidyverse's use of non-standard evaluation (NSE).

Hi there! Thank you for the welcome. That other post does answer my question, thank you very much for the clarification!
